# MATLAB: conversion from matrix to element-by-element multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have this code:

```
KM = [1 0; 0 1];    
syms x, syms y;
% definition of force field 
V = [x y]*KM*[x ; y]
Vdx = -diff(V,x);
Fx = @(x,y) eval(Vdx);
```

The matrix KM dynamically changes the shape of potencial V. The Fx I use in ode solver.
What I want is to be able write Fx(A,B), where A,B is matrix.
I need to convert result of V=(x^2+y^2) to V=(x.^2+y.^2).
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question. Isn't `Fx = @(x,y) -2*KM(1,1)*x-(KM(2,1)+KM(1,2))*y;` when you do the math by hand.

The general V is `V = KM(1,1)*x^2+(KM(1,2)+KM(2,1))*x*y+KM(2,2)*y^2` which is just a quadratic form. Also if is positive definite and symmetric you can simplify it a bit.